# Kubernetes deployment does not persist data after restart, even after deployment yaml is attached to a cloud filestore nfs server

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, persistent-volumes, google-cloud-filestore

I created a Cloud Filestore instance on GCP, standard one, and put in the same VPC that the cluster I have Kubernetes running on. Using this guide https://cloud.google.com/filestore/docs/accessing-fileshares I tried to access the fileshare instance to serve as the persistent storage for my deployment. The deployment I have is a webapp called Apache OFBiz, a set of business tools that are primarily used for accounting. It's demo and documentation is available online as it is open source. So to test if the data persists when I delete a pod, I created a user on the app after exposing the deployment to a public IP, and attached a domain that I have to that public IP. User is created, then when I deleted the user on the cluster using cloud shell, when the pod was created again I accessed the webapp and it didn't have the user anymore, it was back to its base form. I'm not sure what thing is wrong, whether it's the access to the filestore instance, storing and pulling data from the instance. The webapp has an embedded Apache Derby database, just as a note. I guess my question is also if the guide is enough, or do I have to do anything else to make this work, and if there is something else I need to look at.

So here's my deployment yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  annotations:
    deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: "2"
  creationTimestamp: "2021-03-19T21:08:27Z"
  generation: 2
  labels:
    app: ofbizvpn
  managedFields:
  - apiVersion: apps/v1
    fieldsType: FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:metadata:
        f:labels:
          .: {}
          f:app: {}
      f:spec:
        f:progressDeadlineSeconds: {}
        f:replicas: {}
        f:revisionHistoryLimit: {}
        f:selector:
          f:matchLabels:
            .: {}
            f:app: {}
        f:strategy:
          f:rollingUpdate:
            .: {}
            f:maxSurge: {}
            f:maxUnavailable: {}
          f:type: {}
        f:template:
          f:metadata:
            f:labels:
              .: {}
              f:app: {}
          f:spec:
            f:containers:
              k:{"name":"ofbizvpn"}:
                .: {}
                f:image: {}
                f:imagePullPolicy: {}
                f:name: {}
                f:resources: {}
                f:terminationMessagePath: {}
                f:terminationMessagePolicy: {}
            f:dnsPolicy: {}
            f:restartPolicy: {}
            f:schedulerName: {}
            f:securityContext: {}
            f:terminationGracePeriodSeconds: {}
    manager: kubectl-create
    operation: Update
    time: "2021-03-19T21:08:27Z"
  - apiVersion: apps/v1
    fieldsType: FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:spec:
        f:template:
          f:spec:
            f:containers:
              k:{"name":"ofbizvpn"}:
                f:volumeMounts:
                  .: {}
                  k:{"mountPath":"ofbiz/data"}:
                    .: {}
                    f:mountPath: {}
                    f:name: {}
            f:volumes:
              .: {}
              k:{"name":"mypvc"}:
                .: {}
                f:name: {}
                f:persistentVolumeClaim:
                  .: {}
                  f:claimName: {}
    manager: GoogleCloudConsole
    operation: Update
    time: "2021-03-19T22:11:44Z"
  - apiVersion: apps/v1
    fieldsType: FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:metadata:
        f:annotations:
          .: {}
          f:deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: {}
      f:status:
        f:availableReplicas: {}
        f:conditions:
          .: {}
          k:{"type":"Available"}:
            .: {}
            f:lastTransitionTime: {}
            f:lastUpdateTime: {}
            f:message: {}
            f:reason: {}
            f:status: {}
            f:type: {}
          k:{"type":"Progressing"}:
            .: {}
            f:lastTransitionTime: {}
            f:lastUpdateTime: {}
            f:message: {}
            f:reason: {}
            f:status: {}
            f:type: {}
        f:observedGeneration: {}
        f:readyReplicas: {}
        f:replicas: {}
        f:updatedReplicas: {}
    manager: kube-controller-manager
    operation: Update
    time: "2021-03-19T23:19:35Z"
  name: ofbizvpn
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "3004167"
  selfLink: /apis/apps/v1/namespaces/default/deployments/ofbizvpn
  uid: b2e10550-eabe-47fb-8f51-4e9e89f7e8ea
spec:
  progressDeadlineSeconds: 600
  replicas: 1
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: ofbizvpn
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 25%
      maxUnavailable: 25%
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app: ofbizvpn
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: gcr.io/lithe-joy-306319/ofbizvpn
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        name: ofbizvpn
        resources: {}
        terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
        terminationMessagePolicy: File
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: ofbiz/data
          name: mypvc
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      restartPolicy: Always
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
      securityContext: {}
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
      volumes:
      - name: mypvc
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: fileserver-claim
status:
  availableReplicas: 1
  conditions:
  - lastTransitionTime: "2021-03-19T21:08:28Z"
    lastUpdateTime: "2021-03-19T22:11:53Z"
    message: ReplicaSet "ofbizvpn-6d458f54cf" has successfully progressed.
    reason: NewReplicaSetAvailable
    status: "True"
    type: Progressing
  - lastTransitionTime: "2021-03-19T23:19:35Z"
    lastUpdateTime: "2021-03-19T23:19:35Z"
    message: Deployment has minimum availability.
    reason: MinimumReplicasAvailable
    status: "True"
    type: Available
  observedGeneration: 2
  readyReplicas: 1
  replicas: 1
  updatedReplicas: 1
```

Here is my persistent volume yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
 name: fileserver
spec:
 capacity:
  storage: 10Gi
 accessModes:
 - ReadWriteMany
 nfs:
  path: /fileshare1
  server: 10.249.37.194
```

And here is my persistent volume claim yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
 name: fileserver-claim
spec:
# Specify "" as the storageClassName so it matches the PersistentVolume's StorageClass.
# A nil storageClassName value uses the default StorageClass. For details, see
# https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#class-1
 accessModes:
 - ReadWriteMany
 storageClassName: ""
 volumeName: fileserver
 resources:
  requests:
   storage: 10Gi
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want data persistency why not you use `StatefulSet` instead of `Deployment`. You should better use `StatefulSet`.

`Deployment` is basically used for stateless application and `StatefulSet` for stateful applications. In `Deployment` pod's uniqueness is not maintained so when pod created again it is basically do not get previous pod's identify, it gets new name and identity.

StatefulSet is the workload API object used to manage stateful applications. Manages the deployment and scaling of a set of Pods, and provides guarantees about the ordering and uniqueness of these Pods. See k8s [doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/)

A sample `StatefulSet` yaml from k8s doc:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 80
    name: web
  clusterIP: None
  selector:
    app: nginx
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: web
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx # has to match .spec.template.metadata.labels
  serviceName: "nginx"
  replicas: 3 # by default is 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx # has to match .spec.selector.matchLabels
    spec:
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 10
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: k8s.gcr.io/nginx-slim:0.8
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
          name: web
        volumeMounts:
        - name: www
          mountPath: /usr/share/nginx/html
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: www
    spec:
      accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
      storageClassName: "my-storage-class"
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 1Gi
```

In the above example:

- A Headless Service, named `nginx`, is used to control the network domain.
- The `StatefulSet`, named `web`, has a `Spec` that indicates that 3 replicas of the `nginx` container will be launched in unique `Pods`.
- The `volumeClaimTemplates` will provide stable storage using `PersistentVolumes` provisioned by a `PersistentVolume` Provisioner.